# Erro codeigniter no Azure: não acessa as subpastas

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, microsoft-azure, codeigniter-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um sistema ecommerce hospedado no azure( http://lojavirtualcodeigniter1.azurewebsites.net/) Desenvolvido em Framework CodeIgniter 1.7.2 O sistema é carregado no index. Porém, não consigo carregas das demais url que estão na subpastas: Contato, Adm, Carrinho....

**Meu .htaccess :**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Já configurei os arquivos:

- config.php (base().url)
- database.php (conexao)
- autoload.php (url)

Tem alguma outra configuração a ser feita, no azure ou no codeigniter ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolução:

1. Remover o arquivo .htacces do sistema visto que no azure ele não é usado
2. Criar o arquivo com **web.config** com este código(inserir na pasta raiz do projeto). Ele vai permitir o acesso as paginas pelas urls amigáveis:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
             <rewrite>
                 <rules>
                     <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                         <match url="^(.*)$" />
                         <conditions>
                             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                     </rule>
                 </rules>
             </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```